# Cloud Vision returning Chinese name on a logo detection

Tags: google-cloud-vision

We are using Google vision for a while now. The Logo detection doesn't detect so many things but recently the Infinity car brand was detected as "英菲尼迪" logo.
We checked the translation and it means Infiniti! Which is the good point ;-)
Did anybody experience the same issue? And found a way to return the result in a specific language?
Thanks

Comment: It is not possible to specify a certain language for logos detection at present. You can only specify feature type as LOGO_DETECTION when you make the API call. Would you like to see a language parameter added as a new feature in Cloud Vision? You may open a feature request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).